# C++ Print Destructor

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree, destructor

I am using pointers for the first time, my code runs correctly but I need to print a destructor from another .cpp file and don't know how to do so.

After a node is dropped using these two functions:

```
bool LList::remove(node* r) {
    if (r == NULL || search(r->key) == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    if (r == head) {
        head = head->next;
    }
    else {
        node* prev = getb4(r);
        prev->next = r->next;
    }
    r->next = NULL;
    return true;
}
bool LList::drop(int k) {
    node* currentNode = search(k);
    if (currentNode == NULL || !remove(currentNode))
        return false;
    node* tmp = currentNode;
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        currentNode = currentNode->dup;
        remove(tmp);
        tmp = currentNode;
    }
    return true;
}
```

... it correctly prints "(key) removed", using this function from the main.cpp.

```
void testDrop(LList& L) {
    int key;
    cout << "Enter key:  ";
    cin >> key;
    if (L.drop(key))
        cout << key << " removed\n";
    else
        cout << key << " not found in list\n";
}
```

However, I also need it to print the destructor from my node.cpp without altering my main.cpp. Here is the destructor:

```
node::~node() {
    if (next) delete next;
    if (dup) delete dup;
    cout << "NODE DESTRUCT: key=" << key << " data=" << data << endl;
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to `delete r;` ?

Comment: use std::shared_ptr it will call the destructor for you, no modern c++ code should use raw pointers

Comment: @Julianne Wright What does this name getb4 mean?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it is a reference to another function in my code.

Comment: What do you mean by "*print the destructor*"? Your destructor already prints "*NODE DESTRUCT...*", isn't that enough?

Comment: @jtbandes delete r; does print the destructor but then throws an error in my drop function.

Comment: @rustyx I need the destructor to be printed when a node is removed. For example, right now it prints "123 removed" (from the main.cpp) while it should print "NODE DESTRUCT... 123 removed".

Comment: *I need the destructor to be printed when a node is removed* -- If your code doesn't issue a `delete` call, the destructor can't magically figure out you "removed a node".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that by printing you mean executing the destructor. In this case whenever you call delete on an object the compiler sort of checks to make sure that
a destructor is present within the object and then executes it. So in this case you would call `delete n;` where n is your node. Also when you call the remove node method you can also call delete on that node, so long as you're sure that your linked list and node destructor are taking care of the pointers appropriately as to not ruin the order of your list, or cause any other more serious problems such as memory leaks or dangling pointers.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it.

Comment: as i said, use std::shared_ptr, you never need to use raw pointers

Comment: Sometimes there are requirements for using raw pointers, especially if you're taking a CS course on data structures where it's required to use them.

Comment: Not a huge fan of smart pointer linked lists. Recursive destruction can be a real bummer with long lists.